# Displaying Version # In Document

Tags: document-library, excel

I am looking for a way to display the SPItem version number from within an Excel document.  We are authoring an Excel Template in a version controlled document library.  I want the Excel document to display the version number the template is currently on when a user opens it up.  I cannot seem to find an approach. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is probably crazy but since templates are usually updated either rarely or in controlled situations, why not just look at the current version number and then update a specific cell in the template with the expected version number before checking it in?

Comment: my preference is to have this auto updated.  Seems like MS Should have simple ability to display item meta data column values in their own office documents.

Comment: This might be along the lines of what you are looking for (it is for Word but should work for Excel) - http://codebycody.com/2011/07/07/add-the-sharepoint-version-number-to-a-word-document/